# How to find sum of multiple columns in a table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Lottery_details which has these rows:

[image]

I want to find SUM of `count` field with the previous `count` field value of same `digit` field individually . This is the expected result that i want

```
| digit | count | total |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 300   | 25  | 25  | 
| 300   | 27  | 52  |
| 301   | 2   | 2   |
| 301   | 100 | 102 |
| 302   | 2   | 2   |
| 302   | 25  | 27  |
```

this is what i tried yet and the output

```
SELECT `A`.`digit`,`A`.`count`, (SELECT SUM(`B`.`count`) AS countsum FROM `lottery_details` AS `B` WHERE `added_by`=5 AND `B`.`digit` = `A`.`digit` GROUP BY `B`.`digit`) AS `cnt` FROM `lottery_details` AS `A` WHERE `A`.`added_by`= 5
```

[image]

Comment: which version of mysql do you use

Comment: Server version: 5.7.31 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function in MySQL 8.0+ as follows:

```
SELECT `A`.`digit`,`A`.`count`, 
        sum(`A`.`count`) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY `A`.`digit` order by `A`.`created_at`) AS `cnt` 
  FROM `lottery_details` AS `A` WHERE `A`.`added_by`= 5 ;
```

If you are on lower version of MySQL then you can use the following (same as your query with few extra condition in your sub-query)

```
SELECT `A`.`digit`,`A`.`count`, 
       (SELECT SUM(`B`.`count`) AS countsum 
          FROM `lottery_details` AS `B` 
          WHERE `added_by`=5 
            AND `B`.`digit` = `A`.`digit`
            AND `B`.`created_at` <= `A`.`created_at`) AS `cnt` 
 FROM `lottery_details` AS `A` WHERE `A`.`added_by`= 5
```